# Swift 3.0 Writing binary image data with write(toFile: atomically:)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, path, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working through a tutorial [Project10](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/10/4/importing-photos-with-uiimagepickercontroller) and trying to convert it to Swift 3.0 as I go. It is the usually straight forward case of using a **UIImagePickerController** to select an image and then save it to the **Documents Directory**.

I'm getting an error on this line:

```
jpegData.write(toFile: imagePath, atomically: true)
```

Which began life as this:

```
jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
```

The error wants to replace my arguments with:

```
jpegData.write(to: imagePath, options: true)
```

I'm pretty sure that's not what I want and it leads to further String/URL errors anyway. The two methods, in full are:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var newImage: UIImage

    if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }

    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
        jpegData.write(toFile: imagePath, atomically: true)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Am I simply getting confused with Strings, NSStrings and URLs?

Comment: I think one method is `.write(to: , atomically: , encoding: )` ... you can use that like `.write(to: imagePath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: When I try that I get Error: Extra argument 'encoding' in call. I had seen that method in the docs earlier but had forgotten to try it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Well I have made some progress with the following:

```
let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
   try! jpegData.write(to: path, options: [.atomic])
}
```

Ugly and slack with the possible error (for now) but using a version of El Capitan's suggested method and converting the String to an URL moves me forward.

Comment: For me, I used `.atomicWrite` rather than `.dataWritingAtomic` - I don't know if this is a naming change between the relevant beta at the time and the final version of Xcode 8 etc., or if it's different between versions of the macOS APIs.

Comment: interestingly, from the WritingOptions source just above atomicWrite: "Options with old names for NSData writing methods. Please stop using these old names." So now it's just "atomic".

Comment: For me if  data.write(to: path, options: [.atomic] )  works fine

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Swift 3:

```
  if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage!, 80) {
      do {
            try jpegData.write(to: imagePath!)

         } catch {
             print("write image failed")       
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

This is the perfect solution, we need to use try

```
do {
    try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```